# How to configure an existing web.xml in Spring-Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, servlets, migration

We are migrating a J2ee app to spring. It's a maven multi module project.

We want to add a new module with all the spring configuration and the `@SpringBootApplication`.

The old app has a war maven module (actually two of them) with the web stuff.

I thought there would be a way that I can configure some *spring tomcat bean* and just tell it where to find the *deployment descriptor* `web.xml`.

The only thing I found is the `TomcatServletWebServerFactory` where you can configure the war itself `tomcat.addWebapp("/myappscontext", "path/to/myapp.war")`. But I think that's a very unflexable way for our migration project and I didn't succeed with setting up the war file path which is in the *spring boot fat jar* `lib` when the app is deployed.

The only way currently I see is to move the whole `webapp` directory to the new spring maven module. But that doesn't really work because we have a second war in this project.

Comment: The fact that you have 2 wars means you are now also deploying 2 war files to tomcat. Which means you have 2 individual applications for which you both should have a project and an `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class. Without knowing what is in the `web.xml` this question is impossible to answer. Depending on the content we can suggest what to do (you might even be able to remove it).

Comment: OK, that was how the existing J2ee app looks like. We actually can live with just one webapp: the second war is just a app check, which we can include in the actuator health check